# Copy the contents of S3 bucket to another bucket | Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy all the contents of an S3 bucket to another S3 bucket (in the same account) using AWS Lambda (**NodeJs**).

Right now, what I do is to list the contents of the source bucket and then copy them in the destination bucket.

**Is there any better approach to copy all the contents?** *In short, I want a duplicate bucket.*

My code in NodeJs is:

```
    s3.listObjects(sourceBucketParams, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
          console.log("Error while copying files: ", err);
        }

        if (data === null || data === undefined) {
            callback(null, 'All done!');
        }

        if (data.Contents.length) {
            async.each(data.Contents, function(file, cb) {

                var params = {
                    CopySource: sourceBucket + '/' + file.Key,
                    Bucket: destBucketName,
                    Key: file.Key,
                    ACL: 'public-read'
                };
                s3.copyObject(params, function(copyErr, copyData){
                       if (copyErr) {
                            console.log("Error: " + copyErr);
                         }
                     }
                 );
                 callback(null, 'All done!');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

AWS Lambda doesn't seem like the right tool for the job here. What if the copy takes longer than the max Lambda run time? You could write something to get a list of all the objects, and then trigger a Lambda function once for each object, but that seems like overkill.

How about running a one-time `aws s3 sync` [command](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to synchronize the contents of one bucket to another, then configure the buckets with AWS S3 cross-region replication to automatically copy any new objects that are added to the bucket in the future?